# Can't run my Quarkus app after adding JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, testing, quarkus

I'm trying to learn Quarkus, but after adding a JPA dependency the app doesn't initialize anymore.

This is the added dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Following are the errors I'm having:

```
[org.tes.uti.TestcontainersConfiguration] (build-47) Attempted to read Testcontainers configuration file at file:/home/fhb/.testcontainers.properties but the file was not found. Exception message: FileNotFoundException: /home/fhb/.testcontainers.properties (No such file or directory)
```

After that Quarkus keeps on and gets the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Model classes are defined for the default persistence unit <default> but configured datasource <default> not found: the default EntityManagerFactory will not be created. To solve this, configure the default datasource. Refer to https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource for guidance.
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=admin
quarkus.datasource..jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quarkus-social
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=16
```

I think that Quarkus is trying to run tests and for that it needs the **.testcontainers.properties** file, which I've never created. Anyways I don't want to create that file in /home/fhb/, so theres a way to specify that file location?

Besides thatI would like to know if Testcontainers has something to do with unit tests, which I would like to add to my quarkus application.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you running with `mvn quarkus:dev`? Looks like there's a typo at  "quarkus.datasource..jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quarkus-social". There are two dots. If you don't specify the URL of the database, Quarkus uses test containers to start one database for you. There are tutorials on https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource. Here's one example project https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/hibernate-orm-quickstart . About tests, you can use test containers or one in memory database as H2. You can find all this on Quarkus guides.

Comment: Yes, I'm using mvn quarkus:dev, and the problem was the type, I'm feeling kind dumb rn hehe, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is a small typo.

Change from

```
quarkus.datasource..jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quarkus-social
```

To

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quarkus-social
```

If you don't specify the URL of the database and run in `dev` or `test` mode, Quarkus uses test containers to start one database for you.

There are tutorials on quarkus.io/guides/datasource.

About tests, you can use test containers or one in memory database as H2. You can find all this on Quarkus guides.